# Get last inserted id

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Is there any way I can get the last inserted ID if I am using SQL Server CE? I have 2 tables and when a new record is created, I want to be able to save the ID in the second table too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this example will help you.

```
INSERT INTO jobs (job_desc,min_level,max_level) VALUES ('A new job', 25, 100);

SELECT job_id FROM jobs WHERE job_id = @@IDENTITY;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

will retrieve the last auto-generated identity value in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

use this query:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Joe');
SELECT ID AS LastID FROM Persons WHERE ID = @@Identity;
```

or you can view this link for more info:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming higher values of `id` are always newer, how about:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC
```

or:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table
```

Comment: That doesn't account for possible concurrency issues. You're introducing a race condition, hoping your `SELECT MAX(id)` is executed before another record gets inserted. I'd go with `@@Identity` since `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` isn't supported in SQL CE.

Comment: @@Identity assumes the select is run in the same session. It's not clear from the OP that is the case so I think this is the better answer for the information given.

Answer (score -1):

This worked fine for me

```
SELECT TOP (1) your_id FROM your_table ORDER BY your_id DESC
```

Comment: This may work but it is much slower than the approved answer.

Comment: Also, I think this won't account for possible concurrency issues, like that stated in the first comment in Brissles's answer.